# Datatables json data displaying all data on one line

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I am trying to setup datatables to read my json API to display data in a table. Currently it is outputting all of the object contents into one line instead of looping it like a table should be displayed.

My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ufcjbnx/9/)

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Blocks</th>
             <th>Amount</th>
             <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "https://zelcash.voidr.net/api/payments",
            dataSrc : ''
        },
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "payments.[].blocks.[]"
        }, {
            "data" : "payments.[].amounts.t1XHpNtYY2N3EMDRoX9RM2hq4DWWPZSmawJ"
        }, {
            "data" : "payments.[].time"
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Scanning first few items that key used in `amounts` doesn't seem to exist in all of them

Comment: Oh, that could be a bigger issue. I only need a row returned if the address exists in amounts

Comment: Should map/reduce it yourself then probably into simple array then pass to plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need an endpoint to return only an array, because this endpoint https://zelcash.voidr.net/api/payments return some objects.

You can check the datatables documentation: 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax in this example the ajax url is https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt and this return an array.